# Is it possible to create an ASP .NET Core Migration with data in it?

Tags: asp.net-core, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations, data-migration

I am working with migrations in ASP .NET Core and Entity Framework and everything works well to preserve the structure of tables.

However, I would like (if possible) to also have data in migrations, so that a person who checkout my code (and migrations) can also retrieve that data (which would typically be test data or data that is stored in the database).

Is is possible? If not, what would be an alternative?

For example FluentMigrator allows that type of migration :

```
Insert.IntoTable("TestTable").Row(new { Name = "Test" });
```

Comment: probably you need to seed data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql#seed-the-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Entity Framework, migrations are used for creating Database Schema (not the data itself). If you need some type of data that should be included in the database while creating it, you should **Seed** the data while creating the schema.

If you want that one person to also retrieve your data then the connection string of that particular application should point to the same shared database where data actually resides.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think that seeding is exactly what I need.